# SUM of filtered parameters GROUP BY year in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks as follows, and I need to show the **SUM** of **small_bags** values *in selected regions* (Chicago and California) **GROUP BY** years

---

| Row | Date | Small_Bags | Large_Bags | region |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2015-12-27 | 8603.62 | 93.25 | Albany |
| 2 | 2015-12-27 | 48605.95 | 17748.36 | Atlanta |
| 3 | 2015-12-27 | 142543.88 | 2367.22 | BaltimoreWashington |
| 4 | 2015-12-27 | 23520.19 | 5.69 | Boise |
| 5 | 2015-12-27 | 85913.6 | 99.26 | Boston |
| 6 | 2015-12-27 | 55236.68 | 0.0 | BuffaloRochester |
| 7 | 2015-12-27 | 1090140.07 | 110737.35 | California |

I have tried following code but it doest work
(Scalar subquery produced more than one element)

Here's what I've tried

```
SELECT
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Date) AS year,
  SUM(
    (SELECT
      Small_Bags
    FROM
      `training-363808.avocado_data.avocado_prices`
    WHERE
      region = 'Chicago'
    ))
  AS total_small_bags_Chicago,
  SUM(
    (SELECT
      Small_Bags
    FROM
      `training-363808.avocado_data.avocado_prices`
    WHERE
      region = 'California'
    ))
  AS total_small__bags_California

FROM 
  `training-363808.avocado_data.avocado_prices` 

GROUP BY
  year
```

Comment: Can you share your expected output?

Comment: "*it doest work*" isn't a particularly descriptive problem statement - can you share how you know *specifically* that it doesn't work? What did you expect as output? What did you get instead? What error messages (if any) are being kicked back to you? See [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    YEAR(DATE) AS year,
    SUM(CASE WHEN region = 'Chicago'
             THEN Small_Bags ELSE 0 END) AS total_small_bags_Chicago,
    SUM(CASE WHEN region = 'California'
             THEN Small_Bags ELSE 0 END) AS total_small_bags_California
FROM training-363808.avocado_data.avocado_prices
GROUP BY 1;
```